# Unable to access switch management interface

Tags: networking, switch, netgear

On one of my sites, I have a Netgear network ecosystem. This is typically managed by the Netgear insight cloud portal. One of my switches is unreachable from the cloud portal, it also can not be reached by direct IP in a web browser. The switch still appears to route traffic as expected, it is just the management interface that can't be reached.

I do IT for a small business and I'm not the most experienced with networks. Please help!!

Thanks,
B

Comment: Go on site and plug a cable into the management port and verify that it's correctly configured? I don't understand how we can help you.